# Why is Iakobos translated as (J)ames

Tags: translation-philosophy, james, transliteration

Acts 1:13

> When they entered the city they went to the upper room where they were
> staying, Peter and John and James and Andrew, Philip and Thomas,
> Bartholomew and Matthew, James son of Alphaeus, Simon the Zealot, and
> Judas son of James.

Iakóbos: James, the name of several Israelites
Original Word: Ἰάκωβος, ου, ὁ
Part of Speech: Noun, Masculine
Transliteration: Iakóbos
Phonetic Spelling: (ee-ak'-o-bos)
Definition: James, the name of several Israelites
Usage: James, (a) the Small, son of Alphaeus, and one of the Twelve, (b) half-brother of Jesus, (c) father (?) of Jude, (d) son of Zebedee, and brother of John, one of the Twelve, killed A.D. 44.

Book of (J)ames

Comment: That is a quirk of English.  Most languages change names to suit the phonemes of the tongue.

Comment: Welcome to the group, "I believe." This site usually requires a biblical text to start with. To avoid having it closed as off-topic  in the future, please provide a specific bible quote.  In the meantime I will add one; please edit if you like. Also please take a look at the Help and Tour pages (links below, left)

Answer (score 5):

This is part of the progression from Hebrew to Greek to Latin and finally English. The name in Hebrew is pronounced Yaakov (Jacob). This became Iakóbos in Greek, then Iacomus in Latin and finally James in English. The  "bos" in Greek became "mus" in Latin. Later, in the transition from European languages to English, the soft "a" became the long "a" in James and the, the "y" sound of the earlier names turned in a "j" sound. We also get this in the names we use for Jesus and Jehovah.

Other examples:

- Mary - Miryam in Hebrew = Mariam in Greek = Maria in Latin = Mary in English
- Jesus - Y'shua (Joshua) in Hebrew = Iesous in Greek = Iesus in Latin = Jesus in English
- Peter  - Sela (Rock) in Hebrew = Cephas (kefa) in Greek = Petrus in Latin = Peter in English
- The LORD - *yhwh* (unpronounced) in Hebrew = JeHoVa in Latin (pronounced with a "y") = Jehovah in German, also with a "y" = Jehovah in English = Yahweh in some translations.

The list goes on. A good place to research the derivation of Biblical names in English is the [Online Etymological Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=peter)

---

*Note*: This question stimulated me to wonder how "Yaakov" became "Diego" in Spanish. It's an even more convoluted process than with "James." [Here's a plausible hypothesis.](https://wordsonlanguage.medium.com/so-hows-jacob-related-to-diego-1b21bce02185)

Comment: A good answer that shows this is nothing to do with the Bible but the idiosyncrasies of each language.